# How to Design "Country", "Province" and "City" Tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design, rdbms

**EXAMPLE 1:**

```
xTable: xTableID, CountryName, PovinceName, CityName
```

- OR

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
Country: CountryID, CountryName
Province: ProvinceID, ProvinceName
City: CityID, CityName
```

Question:

1. **Do you recommend me to populate country, province and city lists at application level and then use EXAMPLE 1 design? or Should i populate it at DB level as in EXAMPLE 2?**
2. **City will show based on chosen province (if any) or country name. Province (if any) will show based on chosen country. Province will be only for one country and city will only be for one province/country. No one/many to many relations, so i designed it as below**

NOTE: every country will have a city surely but not every country will have a province name.

```
Country: CountryID (PK), CountryName
Province: CountryID (PK - FK), ProvinceName
City: CountryID (PK - FK), CityName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a direct relationship from City to Country, Province to Country and City to Province.
All provinces are in a country, so the Province table needs a CountryID as FK. Likewise all Cities are in a Country, so same there.
As not all Countries have regions that could be called Provinces they can't be used to navigate from City to Country. ProvinceID should be in the City table, but allow null values.

Alternatively you could establish virtual provinces (e.g. Province name = No Province) for countries without Provinces and use them to relate City to Country. That would also work if there was a city which was in a country that has provinces, but wasn't itself in a province (if such a thing exists, possibly the province IS the city).

Comment: I came up with another suggestion that meets yours in someway. I create a new table with following columns: ID, CountryID, ProvinceID, CityID. I know this meets many to many relationship but it looks easier to deal with. Do you have any comments on the stated design?

Comment: I can't say I like it much. It depends on how important it is for you to maintain strict relationships between your entities. The table design will not restrict a City from being related to several countries, you'd have to do that programmatically, which could cause errors. If you want to use your DB to maintain strict relationships then this isn't the way to do it. On the other hand, if you're just interested in a quick and dirty fix to get some code up and running then it will probably work fine :-) You really need your CityID to be primary key. So I'd go with one of the two solutions above.

Comment: Side note: I'm assuming you want to do something with the data like filter dropdown values based on choice of Country & Province. To avoid branching code the virtual province solution (where an imaginary province is created for each country that doesn't have provinces) would be simplest. You might want to check if a country only has an  imaginary province and disable the province dropdown in that case, you could also pre-load the cities dropdown if a country only had one province (imaginary or not).

Comment: You are right. I took your solution to prevent problems that might come down the road....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have modified and used this with some success:
http://www.endswithsaurus.com/2009/07/lesson-in-address-storage.html

The person who wrote the article is a very active SO user:
[BenAlabaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40650/benalabaster)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add ProvinceId and CityId to tables Province and City. A province can have many cities likewise a country can have many provinces. No need to keep countryId in city, ProvinceId would be enough since it will be triggered by Province but not country.

Comment: Not all countries have subdivisions that could be called provinces (think of the Vatican City). Equally other counties have multiple levels of subdivision (e.g. UK: constituent countries are divided into counties).